# Redirect from old page.php?xx to new page/pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have changed CMS (from e107 to Joomla) and after years on the web there are lots of old links to my old deprecated articles like **mysite.com/page.php?60**

So my goal is to redirect all the Google old links (that otherwise give error 404) to new links or global link (the new index page)

This link: https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

gives **EXACTLY** the suggestions I need, with the only little difference that my articles queries are like "page.php?XX" and not "page.php?id=XX"

so I tried this code:

(to redirect to a specific new page)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^60$
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ downloads/program1-download? [L,R=302]
```

(global redirect to home page)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ index.php? [L,R=302]
```

Both codes does not work.... :((

Comment: What does it do? You need a forward slash at the start of the substitution. `/downloads` or `/index.php`. Don't use `[0-9]*` or it will also match empty query strings. Use `+`.

Comment: You might need to set `AllowOverride all` in your config so the `.htaccess` file gets processed.

Comment: What exactly happens when you go to **/uri/?123** .